# Spontaneous flutter / roar sound coming from under hood?

Tags: jeep, noise, grand-cherokee

2004 Jeep Grand Cherokee LE. This has only happened twice: driving between 35-50 mph when suddenly a loud sort of fluttering sound accompanied by a loud whine. The whine evoked the picture of a straining engine, as if something were dragging inside it. This lasts only until the car stops, and is gone once the engine is restarted.

Happened once a year ago, mechanic couldn't reproduce it. Finally happened again last week, but again disappeared after restarting the engine.

It's such a violent sound I worry something very damaging is occurring, but there's no consistency to it.

Note: The fluttering sound can also be heard some when accelerating uphill, but the straining noise has only happened those two times.

Comment: It looks as though the Grand Cherokee has a clutch fan. If so, this could be locking up and causing the noise. When fully locked, it can make quite a racket as well as putting a drag on the engine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the Grand Cherokee has a clutch fan. If so, this could be locking up and causing the noise. When fully locked, it can make quite a racket as well as putting a drag on the engine.

Comment: I'd agree with this diagnosis. Not sure what it is with the viscous clutches on the Jeeps and Dodges from this era - they make an absolute riot when they're running

Comment: Viscous or vicious? ;-)

Comment: Both, by the sound of things :)